# Sending binary data over sockets with Python

Tags: python, sockets

I'm looking to script some basic requests over the [SPDY protocol](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft3). The protocol defines the frames you send as being comprised of binary data of very specific length and byte order.

I've only ever written small programs that send strings across sockets (HTTP). How do I go about implementing a SPDY control frame header for example? I've tried using the bitstring library and numpy to control the size of all the different sections of a control frame header for example but nothing is really working. The current SPDY library for python uses cython and C data types and i've found it to be very unpredictable. I was wondering how I can go about building simple requests with pure python or very simply how do I go about building something precisely like the protocol defines and sending it across a socket?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Generally `bytearray` class will be your friend (if I understand your question correctly). You can send it via socket:

```
my_bytes = bytearray()
my_bytes.append(123)
my_bytes.append(125)

// my_bytes is b'{}' now

s.send(my_bytes)
```

Follow the protocol specification and create byte after byte. This also works when you receive data:

```
data = s.recv(2048)
my_bytes = bytearray(data)
```

I don't know much about SPDY protocol but for example the control bit is the first **bit** (not byte) in the message. You can retrieve it from `my_bytes` via binary AND for example:

```
control_frame = my_bytes[0] & 128
```

this is because `128` is `10000000` in binary and thus binary AND will give you the first bit only (remember that each byte has 8 bits that's why we have 7 zeros).

That's how things are done manually. Of course I suggest using some library because writing a proper protocol handler will take lots of time, you may find it quite difficult and it might not be efficient (depending on your needs of course).

Comment: thanks i'm looking into this, how can I print out the bits in the bytearray as a readable string if i'm initialising each one as 0b...?

Comment: @ubiQ Bits? Bit is just 0 or 1. If you want to print a bytearray simply do `print my_bytes`. Python interpreter should automatically convert each byte to its string representation. Note that it might not be "readable" (depends on what that exactly means).

Comment: I want to read it as a string in the console but it's outputting the raw binary atm

Comment: @ubiQ What exactly do you put in that array? Show me some code. Note that only bytes between 32 and 126 are printable (ASCII).

Comment: control_header = bytearray()
control_header.append(0b1)     # control_flag
control_header.append(0b000000000000010)   # version
control_header.append(0b0000000000000001)   # type
control_header.append(0b00000000)    # flags
control_header.append(0b000000000000000000000000)  # length

print my_bytes

Comment: @ubiQ Yep, as I said: only bytes between 32 and 126 are printable. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: @ubiQ Also note the mistake you are doing: both control bit and version take 2 bytes. But version has 15 bits, i.e. if your version is say `v = 0b000000000000010` and your control bit is `c = 0b1` then your first byte is `first = (c << 7) + (v >> 8)` (which means "add 7 zeros to `c` and add the result to the first half of `v`") and you should do `control_header.append(first)`. Then `control_header.append(v & 255)` (which means "add second half of `v` as a second byte"). As I said: implementing a protocol might be quite difficult.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to define the header format with a string and parse it directly.

To generate a packet:

```
fmt = 'B I 4b'
your_binary_data = pack(fmt, header_data)
sock.sendall(your_binary_data)
```

Where *fmt* indicates the header format ('B I 4b' is just a, clearly not working for your SPDY header, example). Unfortunately, you will have to deal with non-byte-alligned header fields, probably by parsing bigger chunks and then dividing them according to your format.

Aside that, to parse the header:

```
unpacker = struct.Struct('B I 4b')
unpacked_data = unpacker.unpack(s.recv(unpacker.size))
```

*unpacked_data* will contain a tuple with the parsed data.

The *struct module* performs conversions between Python values and C structs represented as Python strings. I have no guarantees about the efficiency of this approach, but it helped me to parse different protocols just by adjusting the *fmt* string.