# python make string from c_char list

Tags: python, c, sockets

How can i make string from a list which contains c_char types.

so for example the C code:

```c
static const char data [] = {0x45, 'b', 'a'}
```

you can send it on socket.

I would like to do this in python. Is it possible? that is important, 1 element 1 byte.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python type [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytearray) to store your values and then send it directly over the socket:

[Sending binary data over sockets with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310152/sending-binary-data-over-sockets-with-python)